# How to make a LoginPage with a SplitView Control?

Tags: xaml, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile, splitview

I make a similar solution of `SplitView` like in a Microsoft Sample [NavigationMenu](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/714722f53c3ae270f634f54cb2740411f6b11032/Samples/XamlNavigation)

So i've got a question. How can i implement a `LoginPage` in project like this? I don't want to make loginPage with `SplitView`. I've tried to make splitview closed if my `AppFrame` is LoginPage, but seems like that solution is too awful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In xaml you can overlay controls.

Instead of having a login page, have a login control which overlays on top of everything when the user is invalidated.

e.g. xaml

```
<Grid>
   <LoginControl />
   <SplitView />
</Grid>
```